# What is the name of this font in this Latex-typeset paper?

Tags: latex, font-face

I like the font used in this paper, but don't know its name.

https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w25136/w25136.pdf

Can someone tell me (1) what is the name of the main font used in the paper, and (2) what is the name of the math font?

Thanks so much.

Cheers

Comment: This may be better fit for https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ See also the [LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/). Or email the author.

Comment: If you open the pdf in adobe reader, you can go to "document properties" and get a list of all the fonts in the document